# Check if a string contains one of the strings in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to check if the team contains one of the following strings in the array. If yes then remove it. Why is it not doing this?

```
function changeName(name) {
  var team = name;
  var removearray = ['.CS', ' Dota2', '-Dota2', ' Esports', 'eSports', ' Tactics', 'DotCom', ' DotA2', ' - LoL', '-LoL', ' Carry', 'Â', ' LoL'];
  removearray.forEach(function( word ) {
      team = team.replace( new RegExp( word, 'g' ), '' );
  });
  return team;
}
```

Comment: start by checking console for errors. `string` is undefined and should likely be `team` instead

Comment: Well, `changename` is indeed not defined.

Comment: @PeterPik, based on the error in your console, you're calling "changename". But the function is "changeName" with a capital N.

Comment: Regular expressions are **not** the right tool for this. For example, your team name `.CS` will match both `.CS`, `ACS` and what ever else. Imagine if a team includes `.*` in its name.

Comment: why use a regex if you're trying to match an exact string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that "forEach" is not supported in certain browsers such as IE8.

Also, please consider the following implementation:

```
function changeName(name) {
  var removearray = ['.CS', ' Dota2', '-Dota2', ' Esports', 'eSports', ' Tactics', 'DotCom', ' DotA2', ' - LoL', '-LoL', ' Carry', 'Â', ' LoL'];
  return team = removearray.reduce(function(previous, current) {
    return previous.replace( new RegExp( current, 'g' ), '' );
  }, name);
}
```

The "reduce" method available in the Array Prototype in Javascript is a very nice way of doing tasks such as this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeName(name) {
  var team = name;
  var removearray = ['.CS', ' Dota2', '-Dota2',
    ' Esports', 'eSports', ' Tactics', 'DotCom',
    ' DotA2', ' - LoL', '-LoL', ' Carry', 'Â', ' LoL'];
  for(var i = 0; i < removearray.length; i++){
      while(team.indexOf(removearray[i]) > -1) {
          var index = team.indexOf(removearray[i]);
          if (index > -1) {
              team = team.substr(0, index) +
                  team.substr(index + removearray[i].length);
          }
      }
  }
  return team;
}

var one = changeName('John'); // returns 'John'
var two = changeName('John Dota2 Doe'); // returns 'John Doe'
var three = changeName('John Dota2 Doe Dota2.CS') // returns 'John Doe'
```